# How much disk space is allocated for Cassandra column having TEXT / VARCHAR data type?

Tags: text, cassandra, varchar, cassandra-3.0, diskspace

Seems there is no any option to specify the maximum number of characters for TEXT or VARCHAR column in Cassandra v3, then how much disk space is allocated for that type of column ? I need that info to evaluate my disk space usage as I have many TEXT columns.

I can't find any relevant information in the net. Please give some useful links in your answers if any.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the out-of-the-box LZ4 compression?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Datastax C client, to do insertions into the cassandra cluster. While inserting a text column, known as string datatype, you need to have variable with the type of "const char *". The size of const char * is fixed and it takes only the number of characters used and will not even consider the NULL character also. So, the text will occupy size based on how many characters you are inserting(and size is equal to that many bytes). Moreover, when we retrieved the data back through read queries, we checked the size and it is equal to the number of characters inserted and null is not initialised at the end.

If cassandra is using some mechanism (like LZ4 compression technique)to compress data, it will be reduced. But, there is no possibility that it will have more than the size of characters of your insertions. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Do you have some links to official documentation containing the assertions made in your answer ?

Comment: I may not be able to get the correct official info regarding this. But, I will give links for compression process in cassandra-https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_config_compress_t.html  And about LZ4- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11051 But Its basic explanation that how can a character datatype have more than one byte. So, I think what I have given in the answer will clearly satisfy your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Datastax has a really good video on how you can [estimate your data size](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/ds220-data-modeling?unit=physical-partition-size). I recommend to attend it.